# Change page body using switch statement

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a menu that when any of the 5 buttons are clicked, it will change the body of the page without changing the menu or anything else, I havent started work on the page re-load yet, im still stuck at this part!

From the index.html

```
<div id="quickstats">
    <p>
        <a href="#" onclick="quickStats(0);"><img src="./images/qstata.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="quickStats(1);"><img src="./images/qstatb.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="quickStats(2);"><img src="./images/qstatc.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="quickStats(3);"><img src="./images/qstatd.png" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="quickStats(4);"><img src="./images/qstate.png" /></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

from the java.js

```
quickStats(x)
{
    var print;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            print="<p>Page A</p>"
            break;
        case 1:
            print="<p>Page B</p>"
            break;
        case 2:
            print="<p>Page C</p>"
            break;
        case 3:
            print="<p>Page D</p>"
            break;
        case 4:
            print="<p>Page E</p>"
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById("currentactivity").innerHTML=print;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the word: `function`.  `function quickStats(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your code:

1. It should be `function quickStats(x)`
2. You need to have an element with the id `currentactivity` for the last line to do anything. Add `<div id="currentactivity"></div>` to the HTML.

Comment: How careless! I forgot the function before quickStats(x), thank you.

I have the id="currentactivity" in there aswell =]